# preg replace complete word using partial patterns in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using `preg_replace($oldWords, $newWords, $string);` to replace an array of words.

I wish to replace all words starting with `foo` into `hello`, and all words starting with `bar` into `world`

i.e `foo123` should change to `hello` , `foobar` should change to `hello`, `barx5` should change to `world`, etc.

If my arrays are defined as:

```
$oldWords = array('/foo/', '/bar/');  
$newWords = array('hello', 'world');
```

then `foo123` changes to `hello123` and not `hello`. similarly `barx5` changes to `worldx5` and not `world`

How do I replace the complete matched word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple if you understand regex, as well as how preg_replace works.

Firstly, your replacement arrays are incorrectly formed.  What is:

```
$oldWords = array('\foo\', '\bar\');
```

Should instead be:

```
$oldWords = array('/foo/', '/bar/');
```

As the backslash in php escapes the character after it, meaning your strings were getting turned into non-strings, and it was messing up the rest of your code.

As to your actual question, however, you can achieve the desired effect with this:

```
$oldWords = array('/foo\w*/', '/bar\w*/');
```

`\w` matches any word character, while `*` is a quantifier either meaning 0 or any number of matches.

Adding in those two items will cause the regex to match any string with foo and x number of word-characters directly after it, which is what preg_replace then replaces; the match.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to loop through the array checking each word, since we are only checking the first three letters I would use a substr() instead of a regex because regex functions are slower.

```
    foreach( $oldWords as $word ) {

        $newWord = substr( $word, 0, 2 );

        if( $newWord === 'foo'  ) {
            $word = 'hello';
        }
        else if( $newWord === 'bar' ) {
            $word = 'world';
        }

    };
```